# DAO.Recordset MySQL Backend Forcing Single Quotation Marks Around Strings

Tags: mysql, dao, ms-access-2016

I have linked tables that are giving me an error "3197". It seems that the following fails with a "3197":

```
.edit
!some_field = "Barbara"
.update
```

it was not always like this. The only way it seems i can hadle this is by either ignoring the error--because everything works beyond getting the error--or by inserting single quotations as so:

```
.edit
!some_field = "'Barbara'"
.update
```

i can do this, but it would be error prone. i have hundreds of lines of code i'd have to change, and i would have to take out the single quotations when reading the table. i store everything as a string.

i have tried every fix from recordlocks in access, and recordlocks in the recordset creation. i have made sure that every table on the server has default entries, and has a primary key. the basic example is where i'm at right now. i am using one specific table, with one specific entry. if i put it in single quotation marks it works.

[edit as per request]

[table create]

```
CREATE TABLE `Client Information` (
  `client_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `client_id_proper` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0000',
  `client_timestamp` timestamp(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_tracking` varchar(255) DEFAULT '2017-01-01',
  `client_id_code39` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'MAC CLIENT 0000',
  `client_name_first` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'unknown',
  `client_name_last` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'unknown',
  `client_name_initials` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'unknown',
  `client_name_artist` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'unknown',
  `client_date_joined` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'unknown',
  `client_role_active_0000` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'unknown',
  `client_role_active_0001` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'unknown',
  `client_role_active_0002` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'unknown',
  `client_role_active_0003` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'unknown',
  `client_phone_home` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'unknown',
  `client_phone_home_unlisted` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `client_emergency_contact` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'unknown',
  `client_emergency_relation` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'unknown',
  `client_emergency_phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'unknown',
  `client_emergency_phone_unlisted` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `client_phone_alternate` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'unknown',
  `client_phone_alternate_unlisted` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `client_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'unknown',
  `client_notes` varchar(1023) DEFAULT 'none',
  `client_id_pwd` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'macbooks',
  PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

[current function]

```
Option Explicit


Public Function Update_Client_Information(persistence_mode As Integer)
'**************************************************************************************************
'**************************************************************************************************
'**************************************************************************************************
'**************************************************************************************************
'**************************************************************************************************

    Dim record_count As Integer


    Dim strSQL As String


    Dim rst_ctl As DAO.Recordset

'**************************************************************************************************
'**************************************************************************************************
'**************************************************************************************************
'**************************************************************************************************
'**************************************************************************************************

    strSQL = "SELECT [client_id]" & _
            " FROM [Client Information]" & _
            " ORDER BY [client_id] ASC"

    Set rst_ctl = dbs_mac.OpenRecordset(strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset)

    If rst_ctl.BOF Eqv True Then

        [Procedures Core].EmergencyExitFunction ("unable to load the artists' records.")

        GoTo Line1

    End If

    rst_ctl.MoveLast: rst_ctl.MoveFirst


    record_count = rst_ctl.RecordCount


    If persistence_mode = 1 Then

        strSQL = _
            "SELECT *" & _
            " FROM [Client Information]" & _
            " WHERE [client_id] = " & record_count & _
            " ORDER BY [client_id] ASC"

        Set rst_ctl = dbs_mac.OpenRecordset(strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset)

        If rst_ctl.BOF Eqv True Then

            [Procedures Core].EmergencyExitFunction ("unable to load the artist's record.")

            GoTo Line1

        End If

        rst_ctl.MoveLast


        record_count = record_count + 1


        rst_ctl.AddNew
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_id") = record_count
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_id_proper") = [Procedures Utility].convert_int_to_proper(record_count)
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_id_code39") = MAC_CLIENT_PREFIX & [Procedures Utility].convert_int_to_proper(record_count)
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_tracking") = Year(Date) & "-" & Format(Date, "mm") & "-" & Day(Date)
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_name_first") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_name_first")
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_name_last") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_name_last")
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_name_initials") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_name_initials")
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_name_artist") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_name_artist")
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_phone_home") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_phone_home")
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_phone_home_unlisted") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_phone_home_unlisted")
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_phone_alternate") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_phone_alternate")
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_phone_alternate_unlisted") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_phone_alternate_unlisted")
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_emergency_contact") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_emergency_contact")
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_emergency_relation") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_emergency_relation")
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_emergency_phone") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_emergency_phone")
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_emergency_phone_unlisted") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_emergency_phone_unlisted")
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_date_joined") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_date_joined")
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_role_active_0000") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_role_active_0000")
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_role_active_0001") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_role_active_0001")
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_role_active_0002") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_role_active_0002")
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_role_active_0003") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_role_active_0003")
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_email") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_email")
        rst_ctl.Fields("client_notes") = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_notes")
        rst_ctl.Update


        [Persist Client].Add_Account_Record

        [Persist Client].Add_Volunteer_Record

        [Persist Client].Add_Rehabilitation_Fund_Record

        [Persist Client].Add_Art_Inventory_Record


    ElseIf persistence_mode = -1 Then


        strSQL = "SELECT *" & _
            " FROM [Client Information]" & _
            " WHERE [client_id] = " & Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_id") & _
            " ORDER BY [client_id] ASC"

        Set rst_ctl = dbs_mac.OpenRecordset(strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset)

        If rst_ctl.BOF Eqv True Then

            [Procedures Core].EmergencyExitFunction ("unable to load the artist's record.")

            GoTo Line1

        End If

        rst_ctl.MoveLast: rst_ctl.MoveFirst


        rst_ctl.Edit
        rst_ctl!client_name_first = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_name_first")
        rst_ctl!client_name_last = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_name_last")
        rst_ctl!client_name_initials = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_name_initials")
        rst_ctl!client_name_artist = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_name_artist")
        rst_ctl!client_phone_home = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_phone_home")
        rst_ctl!client_phone_home_unlisted = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_phone_home_unlisted")
        rst_ctl!client_phone_alternate = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_phone_alternate")
        rst_ctl!client_phone_alternate_unlisted = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_phone_alternate_unlisted")
        rst_ctl!client_emergency_contact = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_emergency_contact")
        rst_ctl!client_emergency_relation = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_emergency_relation")
        rst_ctl!client_emergency_phone = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_emergency_phone")
        rst_ctl!client_emergency_phone_unlisted = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_emergency_phone_unlisted")
        rst_ctl!client_date_joined = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_date_joined")
        rst_ctl!client_role_active_0000 = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_role_active_0000")
        rst_ctl!client_role_active_0001 = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_role_active_0001")
        rst_ctl!client_role_active_0002 = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_role_active_0002")
        rst_ctl!client_role_active_0003 = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_role_active_0003")
        rst_ctl!client_email = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_email")
        rst_ctl!client_notes = Forms!frm_client!frm_client_information("input_client_notes")
        rst_ctl.Update

    End If

Line1:

    If Not (rst_ctl Is Nothing) Then

        rst_ctl.Close

        Set rst_ctl = Nothing

    End If


End Function
```

[image]

Comment: What connector? Mysql version? You followed [connector-odbc-usagenotes-apptips-microsoft-access](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-apptips-microsoft-access.html), especially all tables have proper timestamps, pk and `return matching rows`is enabled?

Comment: mysql odbc 5.3 ansi 64; mysql 5.7.21-ubuntu.16.4; yes

Comment: Form code? Show more! Create statement of the table? ODBC-options settings? Relinked the tables? Update your question with the additional Infos.

Comment: Please provide the error description, and the full code. What kind of recordset is it? Have you tried using ADODB recordsets directly linked to the server?

Comment: common error that means nothing "The Microsoft Access database engine stopped the process because you and another user are attempting change the same data at the same time." i chose dao at the onset of the project because it sounded like the right choice to make. it wouldn't be too much effort to switch, but i still have reason to work with dao based on other people's opinions.

Comment: @computerversteher you are talking about a lot of code. if i didn't post the full 5000 lines of code you would be looking at useless information. my tables are created in access using table manager and uploaded to mysql over odbc. i tweak the tables in workbench. i've compacted and relinked a million times easy. if it's not obvious i'll probably be wasting more time discussing it that i could be using solving it.

Comment: Just the procedure for the beginning (if < 5000 lines). Also create-statement of table and odnc options. This error usually happens when access doesn't recognize its own changes or 2+ changes were made at once in different code parts. E.g. you can force this error by editing a textvalue in a table directly (no form) , switch to other field in same row, then go back and remove changes (without proper timestamp).

Comment: @computerversteher I have the timestamp field. I am not exactly clear what it's supposed to do. i don't see how i'm supposed to use it. i use a date tracking field to keep track of what month the record is for. i only need one record a month, so i don't see why i need to approach the granularity at such a small level. i don't even see how i could use this to prevent locking errors. error 3197 specifically isn't thrown while editing the table, but i do get conflict errors and have stopped trying to edit in the table. i just copy it to excel and then copy back. seems safer that way anyway.

Comment: I see no correct timestamp, what then is most likely the cause of your error. Read the MySql Connector doc carefully and follow their advices for MS access. Most important is a timestamp with `On Update Current Timestamp`and`Default Current Timestamp` in every table! The resulting number of your ODBC options is sufficent, don't use pic if not needed.

Comment: [Using ODBC with Microsoft SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811006.aspx) is for Ms-Sql but the principle is the same. For fun activate your Server query log and have a look what is happening.

Comment: `client_timestamp` timestamp(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL, <<=== this isn't a timestamp????? that document is so vague it would fail english 101 thje one at the top

Comment: Not sufficent as Access is comparing pk, timestamp pairs to determ if a record was edited since it fetched it. as your timestamp stays the same it can't use it. Instead it has to fetch all fields and compare them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166926/discussion-between-computerversteher-and-rebeka-fox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @ComputerVersteher pointed out in decisive english:

the answer to my question is a simple one. MySQL requires that all tables to be updated contain a timestamp field with default=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. the requirement is poorly documented and is selective in nature. if you are having troubles with editing tables as well, this could very well fix that. it has for me.

the following documentation expresses this explicitly, but doesn't really go into any detail

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-apptips-microsoft-access.html

using workbench edit a table. at the bottom of the list add a new field. name it whatever. declare the field timestamp--DELETE THE BRACKETS. add default=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. move the field to your desired place in the list. always click off of the entry before you run apply. this will fill your field with the creation date/time.

and there you have it. simple. 7days simple.